# Angular2 construct object depending on DI

Tags: angular

I have a class in Angular2 that requires DI, I am using typescript and I try to inject my service in the following way into a normal class. (Not a component, I can inject the service in components without any problem)

```
     constructor(@Inject(SidebarService) sidebarService : SidebarService)
```

Before I have tried to annotate the class with `@Inject`in the hopes that this would make typescript generate the necessary code for DI to work.

In both cases, when I try to construct the object, I will get a message telling me that an argument for the constructor is missing.

for example

```
        this.sidebarHelper = new ItemSidebarHelper();
```

Will say `error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`

What would be the correct way to use DI in this case?

Comment: Did you try to annotate with @Injectable() (which means that a class uses DI)?

Comment: @Picci Yes I have, same result :-)

Comment: What is the link between `ItemSidebarHelper` and `SidebarService`? Could provide their contents related to DI? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your comments I edited the answer for usage of a singleton service without dependency resolution:

```
class SidebarService {
  static instance: SidebarService;
  static instantiating: Boolean = false;

  constructor() {
    if (!SidebarService.instantiating) {
      throw new Error("Use SidebarService.getInstance()");
    }
  }

  static getInstance(): SidebarService {
    if (SidebarService.instance == null) {
        SidebarService.instantiating = true;
        SidebarService.instance = new SidebarService();
        SidebarService.instantiating = false;
    }

    return SidebarService.instance;
  }
}

class ItemSidebarHelper {
  private _sidebarService: SidebarService;
  constructor() {
    this._sidebarService = SidebarService.getInstance();
  }
}


var sidebarHelper = new ItemSidebarHelper();
```

> [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/o1i3C1ywDDxzWiBgTlnN?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: Thank you, but in this case it will create a new instance of the 'SidebarService', which is not what is wanted from a service. I'd ideally have that SidebarService be the singleton that I use elsewhere. 

This solution does however work apart from that :-)

Comment: That is how I temporarily solved the issue. But now I need to have the SidebarService created in another component, just to pass it to the Helper, whilst the other component does not actually use the SidebarService directly. It's not *that* clean in my opinion, although it does solve the problem :-)

Comment: I will accept this answer as it effectively solves the problem. Bit of a shame that it doesn't work with the normal DI strategy

Comment: Yes, maybe in the final release we can use the global providers for resolving like using StructureMap in C# - that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can inject Angular's injector into your classes

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-injectors',
    template: `
    <h2>Other Injections</h2>
    <div id="car">{{car.drive()}}</div>
    <div id="hero">{{hero.name}}</div>
    <div id="rodent">{{rodent}}</div>
    `,
    providers: [Car, Engine, Tires, heroServiceProvider, Logger]
})
export class InjectorComponent {
    car: Car = this.injector.get(Car);
    heroService: HeroService = this.injector.get(HeroService);
    hero: Hero = this.heroService.getHeroes()[0];
    constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
    get rodent() {
        let rousDontExist = `R.O.U.S.'s? I don't think they exist!`;
        return this.injector.get(ROUS, rousDontExist);
    }
}
```

From: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#explicit-injector